# I'm planning to put lots of phone chargers on one circuit, how to calculate this

Tags: usb, charging, 5v

This would be primarily for samsung S7 devices.  Would like to be able to charge, say, 256 of them.

They will work in groups of 16, trying to design the power flow of this.  Was imagining that each group of 16 would plug into a USB power strip of some kind, and then each group of 16 would link up to another power strip.

So, 16 groups of 16.

But I think that this will not work on a single 120V/15A power source.  I would like to understand the math involved with how to scale this.

It will probably be more like 100 devices at a time, but trying to understand how to calculate this and know what the limits are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each device would draw up to 10 Watts (assuming 2 amps at 5 volts). If you are using a quick charger, this will be higher.

256 devices at 10 Watts each will draw 2,560 Watts, plus a bit more for power supply inefficiencies, so say 3,000 Watts to get a round number.

A US 15 amp circuit a handle 1,440 Watts, though, to be safe, you should derate it to 80% or 1,152 Watts. A 20 amp circuit will handle 2,400 or 1,920 Watts at 80%.

Summary, you’ll need to split them up onto separate circuits, either 3 x 15 amp or 2 x 20 amp.

Comment: This is very helpful.  So, plan on 80% efficiency and work in watts not amps or volts.  This seems basic, I'm sure, but in my world amps are more countable because I'm dealing with lots of devices.

Comment: Don't do this. 30 Samsubng chargers is 15A it says so on the label

Comment: took me a minute to do some math on my own... would seem like 64 devices could fit on one 120v/15a, more if you want to push it

Comment: @jasen I would assume the values on the label are already including a margin (like 80%), but the math would reveal more.  In practice, I will probably go more like 50% just to make sure nothing is grossly out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

[image: boilerplate on samsung 15W charger]

0.5A in.  30 of those and your general purpose outlet is at capacity
so you'd need nine 15A circuits to run your collection of chargers.

Now, 0.5A at 110V is 55W  which suggests the charger has a power factor of only about 0.3

If you need 3KW of charging, start with a power-factor corrected 5V supplies. and connect a bunch of USB sockets to that, you then you only need two 15A circuits.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying.  Another element of this is that the devices will always be plugged in, which is a bit different from many devices doing a full draw at all times.

For the most part, they will always be charged, and at their own interval will pull as needed.

Comment: I want to have up to 256 devices running at the same time and not have to swap them out to charge.  In practice it will be fewer devices, but that's the idea.

Comment: that's a different question now.  use a single 5V supply capable of many amps (say 100A) which has a current limit, Should the devices ever want more than 100A in total the voltage will reduce until the charge rate is under control.

Comment: I apologize if the original question was not specific enough... It takes a minute to get all the details out there.  I'm in a mode of trying to buy parts for this project, and it seems like if I plan on 64 devices per channel would be well within bounds.  Would be great if 128 worked, but that would seem to push boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

I'd really avoid this.

Having several 10s amperes around will give heavy and unpredictable voltage drop on the 5V lines.

Heavy because you'll find that even  huge cable gauges will not keep power within specs, not mention that USB connection to your groups of 16 will probably melt down.

Unpredictable because voltage drops will depend on actually sunk current, varying with number of phones and their batteries status.

In turn I believe the only viable option is a bunch of individual 230V to 5V USB power supplies, one for each phone.

[image]

Something like the above, it can be installed like a conventional AC socket but it can supply a couple of phones

Comment: Please say more... what is your definition of "a bunch of individual 230V to 5V USB power supplies"... like what grouping would you propose?

Comment: @TheMolecule have a look at my edits, cheers.